# For loop and add <li> to <ul> multiple times

Tags: javascript, for-loop, append, appendchild

I know this should be relatively simple, but trying to get this to work...

- I have 3 divs, which contain `<li>`'s.
- I want to loop through all my divs, (by classname `.fare-benefits`).
- To find the div, which only has 1 `<li>`.
- Once I've looped through and found the div, with only 1 `<li`>, I want to add an additional 8 empty `<li>`'s, to it's parent `<ul>`.

For some reason, I keep getting the following error:

`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined"`

I've created an example of my code below. Any pointers?

```js
let fareBenefitsDiv = document.querySelectorAll(".fare-benefits");

  for (let i = 0; i < fareBenefitsDiv.length; i++) {
  
    if (fareBenefitsDiv[i].childElementCount === 1) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        let createLI = document.createElement("li");
        createLI.classList.add("fare-benefit");
        fareBenefitsDiv[i].appendChild(createLI);
      };
   };
};
```

```css
.cards {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.fare-benefit {

  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">

  <div class="row-1 fare-benefits">
    <ul>
      <li class="fare-benefit">1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row-2 fare-benefits">
    <ul>
        <li class="fare-benefit">1</li>
        <li class="fare-benefit">2</li>
        <li class="fare-benefit">3</li>
        <li class="fare-benefit">4</li>
        <li class="fare-benefit">5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row-3 fare-benefits">
    <ul>
      <li class="fare-benefit">1</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">2</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">3</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">4</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">5</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">6</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">7</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">8</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">9</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: You are using the variable name `i` in both loops. Use a different name for the inner loop.

Comment: Also, `i < 9` will create 9 additional LI. Use `i < 8` to create 8 of them.

Comment: You can also get rid of the outer `i` with a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're reusing the variable `i`. So when you use `fareBenefitsDiv[i].appendChild(createLI);` it's using the `i` that counts the number of `<li>` to add, not the index of the DIV.

You can avoid problems like this, and also simplify code, by using `forEach` instead of a `for` loop.

Another problem in your code is that all the DIVs only have one child element, the `<ul>`. You should be iterating over the `<ul>` elements and appending to them, not the DIV.

```js
let fareBenefitsUL = document.querySelectorAll(".fare-benefits ul");
fareBenefitsUL.forEach(ul => {
  if (ul.childElementCount === 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      let createLI = document.createElement("li");
      createLI.classList.add("fare-benefit");
      createLI.innerText = 'x';
      ul.appendChild(createLI);
    };
  };
});
```

```css
.cards {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.fare-benefit {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">

  <div class="row-1 fare-benefits">
    <ul>
      <li class="fare-benefit">1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="row-2 fare-benefits">
    <ul>
      <li class="fare-benefit">1</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">2</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">3</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">4</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="row-3 fare-benefits">
    <ul>
      <li class="fare-benefit">1</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">2</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">3</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">4</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">5</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">6</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">7</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">8</li>
      <li class="fare-benefit">9</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your inner loop's `i` is shadowing the outer loop's `i`. Rename the variable or store the div in a variable first:

```js
let fareBenefitsDiv = document.querySelectorAll(".fare-benefits");
for (let i = 0; i < fareBenefitsDiv.length; i++) {
    if (fareBenefitsDiv[i].childElementCount === 1) {
        const div = fareBenefitsDiv[i];
        for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            let createLI = document.createElement("li");
            createLI.classList.add("fare-benefit");
            div.appendChild(createLI);
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: Indeed, there are several ways to do this. I'm just sticking with the original code to showcase what went wrong there and how to fix it with almost no alteration. Although true, a different kind of loop would also fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much! @kelvin Schoofs!  I've been writing JavaScript for over 2 years and it's the first time I've encountered that issue!  I'll also refactor later to use for.. of. Thanks all!

Comment: My first comment was in response to Barmar's comment, but it seems he deleted it. @ReenaVerma Remember to mark the most helpful answer as the solution.

Comment: Will do, I had to wait before I could "accept" as answer